# Why does c++ range based for loop calls destructor at every iteration?

Tags: c++, foreach, iterator, destructor

I am using a range based for loop to read (and parse) a file using an iterator. My loop looks like this:

```
for (auto record : reader) {
    if (even)
        record.reverse_complement();
    cout << record.write();
    even = !even;
}
```

I have added outputs to the constructor and destructors of the iterator and it looks like the destructor is beign called on the iterator returned by end() in every iteration of the for loop.

```
calling fq_iter FULL constructor 
calling fq_iter default constructor 
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_iter destructor on 0
calling fq_reader destructor on 0
```

These are the classes I am using to parse and iterate over the file, any idea why the destructor is being called at every iteration? (other than that, it produces the correct output).

Comment: What compiler and version?

Comment: Possibly because your iterator's comparison operator takes a value, not a reference, and that's why the `end()` value has to be copied and then destructed?

Comment: You need to provide some information as of what the type of `reader` is, the iterator `fq_iter` and how it is instrumented.

Comment: Does your iterator's `operator++` return a value instead of a reference?

Comment: what you see is iterator specific behavior. you need to post your iterator implementation here.

Comment: To be able to draw any conclusions, you really need to trace all of the constructors, the destructor and the assignment operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to section 6.5.4 of the C++ Standard, your compiler is not supposed to do that.  Instead, it's supposed to cache the end iterator in an unnameable local.

Does your `operator!=` make a copy of the iterator (accidental pass-by-value)?

Comment: Spot on! I had : bool operator!=(const fastq_iterator);. Switched to:     bool operator!=(const fastq_iterator&); and now it's not calling the destructor multiple times anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a local copy of record each time. Try auto&

Comment: He's looking at the destructor of the iterator, not the collection content.

Answer (score 1):

I am not a C++ guru, but I can attests that I landed here because I had the same problem described by the poster, and after reading Neil Kirk's comment, the issue disappeared by adding an '&' after the 'auto' keyword:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

class Foo
{   
     int foo;
public:
    Foo() :foo(0) { std::cout << "Foo()" << std::endl; }
    Foo(int foo_) :foo(foo_) { std::cout << "Foo(int)" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Foo() { std::cout << "~Foo" << std::endl; }
    int getFoo() { return foo; }
};

int main()
{
    std::array<Foo, 10> mainFoo = {0,11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99};

    //No destructors are called in this loop:
    for (auto aiter = mainFoo.begin(); aiter != mainFoo.end(); aiter++)
    {
        std::cout << aiter->getFoo() << std::endl;
    }

    //Destructors are called in this loop without the '&' in 'auto&':
    for (auto& i : mainFoo)
    {
        std::cout << i.getFoo() << std::endl;
    }
}
```